# macOS cannot verify the developer of "clang"

Tags: android-ndk, macos-catalina

I updated to macos-catalina and I am trying to crosscompile c++ code for android using `android-ndk-r18b`

> macOS cannot verify the developer of “clang". Are you sure you want to open it?

It asks me for all different executables/compilers (e.g `arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib`). I got around this by got around it by going to `Security & Privacy` and allowing all executables that show up there. Is there a more generic way to authorize everything within the android ndk?

Comment: Interesting, because we didn't see the same thing when we tried this on Catalina the other day. We got the NDK from Studio when we tried it. Did you download yours directly from the website? I'm wondering if maybe clicking the one top level "are you sure?" in Studio approves all the files it then downloads, and that's why we didn't see it.

Comment: I downloaded it manually from here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases
Where is the top level "are you sure?"

Comment: "Where is the top level 'are you sure?'" Sorry, I worded that vaguely. When you get the NDK via Android Studio, you have to click through a similar process you're describing for Android Studio ("macOS cannot verify the developer of Android Studio" or similar), and my guess is that when that is accepted it transitively accepts the NDK that Studio then installs. I can't back that up yet, but it seems plausible.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't let me download a specific version of the ndk. Only the latest with `sdkmanager ndk-bundle`

Comment: Newer versions (3.5+) have multiple versions available (https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#command-line for instructions). ndk-bundle will always be the latest version available (currently r20). You'll probably want to subscribe to https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1060. We're working on it, but our build/release tooling doesn't currently support this. I'll be trying to up the priority on that since it looks like this is much more of a hassle for non-SDK installed NDKs.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I checked out the guthub issue. I tried installing it via the command line using `sdkmanager --install "ndk;major.minor.build"`
I couldn't really find major and minor versions. I checked the `source.properties` and it says: `18.1.5063045` but `sdkmanager --install ndk;18.1.5063045` doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try again. There was a bunch of lag in getting older NDKs re-published following the change that made it possible. Apparently pre-r19 versions only got to the stable channel earlier today.

Comment: You want me to try redownloading the ndk?

Comment: I just mean that r18 should show up for you now. I think if you download the NDK via the SDK manager then you shouldn't have the Catalina verifier issues.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The problem I have is that I cannot download ndk18 with the sdk manager. I can only download ndk20 using the sdk manager. Or ndk18 by manually downloading it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Really? `Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;18.1.5063045"` worked for me. Maybe you need to update the `sdkmanager` itself? Not sure how to do that.

Comment: See the following link, accepted answer solved it for me. [Cannot use old ndk android ndk r17c after catalina upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390545/cannot-use-old-ndk-android-ndk-r17c-after-catalina-upgrade-due-to-new-security)

Comment: @OnatKorucu Yeah that works. But is not really a nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open `System Preferences/Security & Privacy/Developer Tools.
2. Allow Terminal app to run software locally that does not meet system's security policy

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this enables running all the executables via the Terminal app

Answer (score 1):

This was essentially answered in the comments by Dan Albert, but to add an actual answer, as per [android ndk issue 1060](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1060):

> For macOS, the SDK manager is the most reliable method of acquiring the NDK for most use cases and should be preferred until something else changes. That is not viable for all users, but if it is an option for you that's your best option.

In other words, if you install/reinstall an NDK using SDK manager, you should end up with a version that gatekeeper will be happy about, e.g.:

`android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;18.1.5063045"`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to update the ndk to R21. if your Macos version is catalina.

**"No Mac NDK before NDK r21 was signed or notarized."**

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the Mac App Bundle version of the NDK available since r21 from [this page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads).