# Cannot use old NDK (android-ndk-r17c) after Catalina upgrade due to new security

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-ndk, macos-catalina

After upgrading to macOS Catalina, my project won't build anymore. This is due to Catalina believing the binaries in 'android-ndk-r17c' to not be from a trusted developer.

You get messages such as: 
"“ld” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified."
"macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware"

I have to use the old NDK due to problems with native openCV library SDK and newer NDKs. They are working on it, but the newer SDK is not stable enough for me yet.

I was able to get around "clang" and "clang++" not being able to work by going to the security pane and clicking "Allow Anyway" on the security alerts. However, when trying this with "Id", I can get past the first warning by clicking "Allow Anyway" but it seems to be called subsequently and on the subsequent call I do not have the option to allow it to open.

There is no code really. I just have (and have had for a long time) Android Studio NDK reference pointing to the old NDK via the config.

In IDE from NDK, it fails to load "Id":

"“ld” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified."
"macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware"

Comment: See https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1060. I don't know why you were only able to allow some of them though. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I just found the solution.

It's a tedious process but:

1. MacOS: Open up System Preferences
2. MacOS: Go to Security & Privacy (keep this one open, you'll need it for the entire process)
3. Unity: Go and build your project. When the error appears click "Cancel"
4. MacOS: In the Security & Privacy window - go and click "Allow" near the "clang" error - so that the MacOS system will recognize the app and utilise it.
5. The error will appear again, but this time will ask you to "Open" it. Click "Open"
6. The build will fail several times due to various dependencies, but it will fail with different files that you will need to allow as in the previous steps.
7. Build again your project.
8. If it fails, do the steps again, until it stops failing. Every single error you get with the file not being recognized will be different each time

Comment: additional:
If you did `sudo spctl --master-disable` before, there exists 3 options below 'Allow apps download from: ', you should selected the second one named 'App store and identified developers' in step 4, so you can see the 'Allow' and 'clang' error.

Comment: Please add to the instructions that you need to be on the General tab of Security and Privacy to see the security message.

Comment: Try many times until doing command from linjiang and it work well. Thanks both

Answer (score 20):

There is a better way to work it around now.

You could got to Security & Privacy, open `Developer Tools` and add your terminal app to the list of the tools. The same could be done for your IDE.

Comment: Perfect solution ! I just add Android Studio in `Developer Tools`, ndk can be run now.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Works with Android Studio 4.1 in Apr 2021 still

Answer (score 12):

To allow apps downloaded from Anywhere on MacOs Catalana do this:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Comment: Does this actually do anything? I still can't run anything

Comment: This may remove a few steps.. so we need to hit "allow" then "open".. otherwise every single lib that is used by each tool must be allowd this is a nightmare apple. let us do it per folder basis..

Comment: So For "Anywhere" to show up, you have to leave the Security And Privacy module  the Settings. However, now I still get the "cannot be verified" message, but there is no allow or open anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add to Mudassar Ashraf's answer.

If you don't see «**Allow**» option after clicking «**Cancel**», switch «Allow apps downloaded from» in Security window to «**App Store and identified developers**». This somehow will make «**Allow**» button appear. Then switch it back to «**Anywhere**». Repeat if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If by some reason in your **Security & Privacy window** button **allow** doesnt appear then just move your ndk to different directory and try whole process again.

Answer (score 1):

Find your `clang++` program inside the ndk directory (ndkpath/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/) then right click and open

Answer (score 0):

The solution is mentioned above. go to Terminal and run this code to allow apps from "Anywhere" and in security make sure "Anywhere" is selected. This will prevent from asking you 100 times if you want to allow xxx file downloaded from xxx as well as multiple build failures.

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```